# Prove recursively function f(x) is O(n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, asymptotics

The function is defined by $f :\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^+$
and $f(n) = 2f(\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor)+1$ for $n \geq 2$ with 
$f(1) = 1$.

How to prove that $f(n) = O(n)$ for $n \geq 1 $?

---

base on the calculations,

$f(1) = 1$,

$f(2) = f(3) = 3$,

$f(4) = ... =f(7) = 7 $

I saw that the $2^{k}$term to $2^{k+1} -1$ term is equal to $2^{k+1}-1$ where $k=1,2,...n$

But i have no idea how i starts the proof. Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of proving $f(n)=O(n)$, prove the stronger claim $f(n)\le 2n-1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but how can i obtain the claim?

Comment: @eulerisgood: Long induction on $n$, splitting into cases for the $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ depending on whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I got how's the inequality work, but how can this related to $f(n) = O(n)$ ? Since $2n-1$ is $O(n)$?
Sorry for annoying but really thanks!!!

Comment: @eulerisgood: Yes -- you should be able to use the definition of $O({\cdot})$ to prove directly that such transitive reasoning works in general.

Comment: I am worrying my proof is not rigorous enough. I'm proving $f(k+1) \leq 2(k+1)-1$

and i write $f(k+1) \leq 2(2\lfloor(\frac{k+1}{2}-1)\rfloor-1) +1 = 4\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor-1$

And i split two case ( k is odd and even ). It is easy that if k is odd, $4\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor-1 = 2(k+1) -1 $

But i am wondering can i write $4\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor-1 \leq 2(k+1)-1$ when k is even?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98781/discussion-between-eulerisgod-and-henning-makholm).

Answer (score 1):

I claim that

$$2^{k-1}\le n<2^k\implies f(n)=2^k-1.$$

By induction, we have

- base case:
  $$2^{1-1}\le1<2^1\implies 1=2^1-1$$ is true.
- Inductive step:

$$2^k\le n<2^{k+1}\implies 2^{k-1}\le\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor<2^k\implies 2f\left(\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor\right)+1=2(2^k-1)+1=2^{k+1}-1.$$

---

Now it should be clear that

$$n\le f(n)<2n$$ and $$f(n)=\Theta(n).$$

---

The function $f$ is what you get by setting all bits of $n$ (e.g. $100101011_b\to111111111_b$).